# React Native Elements Avatar won't align

Tags: react-native, flexbox, icons, font-awesome, avatar

I am trying to align the Avatar Icon on the right side. The avatar is from React Native Elements. So I created the Avatar like they say in the documentation:

```
 <Avatar
        small
        rounded
        icon={{ name: "user", type: "font-awesome" }}
        onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        containerStyle={{
          marginRight: 20,
          marginTop: 20,
          alignSelf: "flex-end"
        }}
   />
```

And the container has the following CSS:

```
container: {
    flex: 1
}
```

If I look at it in the inspector, the avatar is in the right place, but the icon is still stuck on the left. Am I missing something in the CSS?

[image]

Comment: It's problem with your MapScreen not about Avatar icon, it might be some conflict. Please check your code again...

Comment: @Seyha I also thought of that, but my Map also has the style of container--> so flex:1.

Comment: You could please try on **avatarStyle** instead of **containerStyle** it might be help

Comment: just tried it, did not make a difference

Comment: @Seyha I tried to recreate it in Expo https://snack.expo.io/Byw2OOyHf . It works there, so it probably really an issue with the MapView

Comment: Ha ha ha... Great, happy to hear you found the solution :)